# How to make a value unique for 2 fields in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I need all values in 2 fields to be unique for both of them. I have **username** and **email** in my custom User model. I want to prevent this:

user1 - username = some_username, **email = MY@EMAIL.COM**

user2 - **username =  MY@EMAIL.COM**, email = some_email

I don't want to constrain '@' or '.' so what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I just overwrote clean():

```
    def clean(self):
        if MyUserModel.objects.filter(Q(username=self.email) | Q(email=self.username)).exists():
            raise ValidationError(self.EMAIL_VALIDATION_ERROR_MASSAGE)
        super().clean()
```